# Programmatically Change IE to Allow Third Party Cookies

Tags: vb.net, security, internet-explorer, cookies

[image]

How can I force IE to accept third party cookies using an App I can just have my field techs run on their laptops?

Is it a registry thing? 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182569

Any help would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a registry setting.  However it is most likely going to be controlled through group policy or Local policy.

I would look at deploying that setting through group policy.  If you have a domain of course.  If you don't have a domain. I'd look at some tools to automate the deployment of local policy settings such as this link.

[LocalPolicy Utilities](http://blogs.technet.com/b/fdcc/archive/2008/05/07/lgpo-utilities.aspx)

It appears Microsoft hasn't left much in the way of managed code to programmatically change this.  However they have a C++ api for this [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ...

I would look specifically at opening the local machine policy if not on a domain.
Described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: No matter what direction you take on this, if the users PC becomes part of a domain it could decide to start using the domain level or organizational unit policy if the administrator applies one.

Comment: No domain, they are Verizon Netbooks that are rarely connected to the internet. Thank you for your help.